# Looking for NPM repository cache

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, npm

I am a bit new to node.js , 
and I found that the dependency model in which versions of dependent packages can be "approximately to" are sometimes problematic for me. 
In addition I would like to overcome situations of network outage and dependency on the internet for my node modules. 
I was thinking about a solution of hosting a local repository that can serve my organization.  
Can someone recommend me of a good solution for implementing this? 

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You can try the sinopia  node-modules to host a private registry.

Answer (score 0):

Using the sinopia to implement a private registry. [link]:(http://thejackalofjavascript.com/maintaining-a-private-npm-registry/)